# Simple Rails form: undefined method `categories_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

As a first-time Rails user, I have to say I'm loving the Rails way of doing things. However, I'm running into an issue trying to create a simple form. I get the following error:

```
undefined method `categories_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f0440365880>:0x007f0430256cd8>
```

I tried creating a `categories_path` method in the controller (though I'm not sure what it would be for), but that didn't fix the error. Any rails experts out there know what's going on?

Here's the relevant code:

**views/category/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @category do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :category %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %><br />
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
Jackeyes::Application.routes.draw do
  scope "/admin" do
    resources :product, :category
  end
end
```

**category_controller.rb**

```
class CategoryController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @category = Category.all
  end

  def new
    @category = Category.new
  end

  def create
    @category = Category.new(params[:category])
    @category.save
  end

end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make your resources plural:

```
resources :products, :categories
```

And try again.

Comment: Thanks! Did that and now I'm getting this error: `No route matches [GET] "/admin/category/new"`. Do I need both singular and plural?

Comment: @David The Rails-way is `/admin/categories/new`. Make sure you have restarted your app. Your path-helpers will respect your new paths (I hope you didn't hard-code links).

Comment: Ah, right. Okay I went to `/admin/categories/new` and I'm getting a routing error: `uninitialized constant CategoriesController`. Any ideas what that might be?

Comment: Oh, is my controller supposed to be plural as well, even though the model name is singular?

Comment: @David Yes, it's the same thing: you didn't follow the conventions. You have to have `CategoriesController`, but you have `CategoryController`. Rename your file from `category_controller.rb` to `categories_controller.rb`. Do the same to the class. Model HAS to be singular, in order to make readable sentences as `Product has_many :orders`. Try to read it as `Products` and you'll be very confused )

Comment: Awesome! That actually makes sense. Pluralized the controller name and it works fine now. Thanks!